# asynchronous process cleanup in elixir

Tags: asynchronous, elixir

I'm building an Elixir app that consumes messages from RabbitMQ. Using the `amqp` library, I've got a `gen_server` set up that subscribes to Rabbit, and handles incoming messages. What I want, is for each incoming message to be processed asynchronously. That's easy - I can grab the message, stick it in a `Task` and fire it off. What's making it a bit more complicated is that I *also* want to `ack` or `nack` the message *after* the task that's processing it finishes. To do that, I need to supervise the task (either through an actual `Task.Supervisor` or just `Process.monitor`), and then wait for an `EXIT` signal.

Here's where things get a bit confusing for me. I can't seem to find a way to asynchronously wait for a process exit. I either have to use `Task.yield` to catch the exit signal, or run a `receive` message loop (which is blocking). The way out seems to be to run an intermediate task/supervisor to wrap the cleanup logic, but it seems ugly.

So, as I understand it, I need:

```
:my_app -> parent Task.Supervisor -> cleanup task -> some form of supervision -> work Task
```

Is that right? If not, what is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your RabbitMQ consumer is a GenServer, you can start tasks with `async_nolink` and handle their completion or failure in `handle_info`

From [the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.Supervisor.html#async_nolink/2-compatibility-with-otp-behaviours)

> Compatibility with OTP behaviours
>
> If you create a task using async_nolink inside an OTP behaviour like
>   GenServer, you should match on the message coming from the task inside
>   your GenServer.handle_info/2 callback.
>
> The reply sent by the task will be in the format {ref, result}, where
>   ref is the monitor reference held by the task struct and result is the
>   return value of the task function.
>
> Keep in mind that, regardless of how the task created with
>   async_nolink terminates, the caller’s process will always receive a
>   :DOWN message with the same ref value that is held by the task struct.
>   If the task terminates normally, the reason in the :DOWN message will
>   be :normal.

Comment: This seems great on the surface, but as I think about it - doesn't this then force me to maintain a mapping of task pids :: messages? While I could pass that info in the result, if the task crashes, the only thing I have to go on is the `ref`..

Comment: Yes definitely more book keeping with this approach. For the convenience of a fire-and-forget style, I think your original approach of a short lived wrapper process which monitors a worker process is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t wont to mess up with handling exit info from the tasks, the easiest approach would be to provide your own helper to wrap the task to execute it and *then* ack. It might look like:

*in your rabbit `GenServer`*

```
def ack_me(channel, tag), do: Basic.ack(channel, tag)
```

*wrapper*

```
defmodule TaskAckHelper do
  async_ack((() -> any), {binary(), bynary()}) :: Task.t
  def async_ack(fun, {channel, tag}) do
    Task.async(fn ->
      fun.()
      Rabbit.ack_me(channel, tag)
    end)  
  end
  async_ack({atom(), atom(), [any()]}, {binary(), bynary()}) :: Task.t
  def async_ack({mod, fun, args} {channel, tag}) do
    Task.async(fn ->
      apply(mod, fun, args)
      Rabbit.ack_me(channel, tag)
    end)  
  end
end
```

Now in `consume` you might simply:

```
TaskAckHelper.async_ack(fn -> IO.puts(:ok) end, {channel, tag})
```

This example is a bit contrived, in real life you would probably want to implement and spawn a [`Task.Supervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.Supervisor.html#async/2) to orchestrate tasks created from `TaskAckHelper`, but it would work as expected even without it (though it’s advised to have a supervisor to trap exits.)

Comment: This gives me a way to ack, but not a way to nack if the process (or `fun.()` in your example) crashes. Your comment about using a supervisor to trap exits puts me back at my original question - if I understand correctly, I need two layers of them, which seems off.

Comment: `Task.Supervisor` is just a handy way to handle `Task` exists you are not interested in. I linked a documentation, there should not be any problem to read it. For `nack`s, there would be no magic: if you need to `nack` on crashes, no fairy will handle crashes for you: surround the underlying call with `try` block and `nack` in `rescue`.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of my question. I'm not asking how to handle acks and nacks, I'm asking about the process tree structure I seem to need to be able to handle them asynchronously from the Consumer.

Comment: Then either implement `handle_info` as said by @MikeBuhot and return from the spawned process the `[channel, tag}` tuple back, or introduce a `Task.Supervisor` and handle returns from there (preferred IMHO.)

Answer (score 0):

It’s not advised to recommend an external packages on SO; I wanted to post it as a comment, but posting as an answer for the sake of formatting.

There is a package to enhance `Task.Supervisor` functionality, called [`Tarearbol`](https://github.com/am-kantox/tarearbol). It allows to delegate the task outcome’s handling to 3-rd party, specifying the callbacks and the default behavior:

```
Tarearbol.ensure fn ->
  result = PROCESS
  {:ok, result}
end, accept_not_ok: false,
     attempts: 3,
     on_success: fn -> ACK end,
     on_fail: fn -> NACK end
```

It will handle crashes internally, retry `attempts` times and call the callback then.